# Using jQuery with partial views in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a View with the following layout
[image]

The parent View is composed of several PartialViews as ilustrated in the picture. One of which is a list where each item has a corresponding Edit button which loads the item into another PartialView, but this is loaded via ajax into a modal dialog-bootstrap. This part works fine.

The problem I have is that no script or jquery event related to the controls of this modal gets executed. For example datepicker widget is never displayed, can not capture the change event of the dropdown, or capture the submit event for the form or the click event of Submit button. 
All the scripts are placed in the main View. for example this is the event handler for the modal submit:

```
$(function () {
            $('#myModal form').on('submit', function () {
                console.log("okk");
                clearErrors();
                $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (data, status) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $("#details").html(data);

                }).error(function (error, status, a, b) {                    
                    $('.modal-body p.body').html(error.responseText);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

In my _Layout.cshtm I have included the necessary scripts (I think):

```
@Scripts.Render("~/js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/globalization")        
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </div>
</body>
```

where "~/js" is:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                "~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive-custom-for-bootstrap.js",
                "~/Scripts/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.js"
                ));
```

What could be the problem with my scripts and jQuery for this dialog ? Indications from similar questions in the site have not worked for me so far.

I have tried to express as clearly as possible if something is not understood the code or the illustrations I'm all ears. Thank you

Comment: What happens when you debug JavaScript? Does for example `$('#myModal form')` return any items?

Comment: @DavidTansey, I just tried to move the scripts to the partial but i get the error "$ is undefined" in the firebug console

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, that event never gets executed :(

Comment: thanks @KyleGobel, let me ask. It is not supposed that jquery is already available in the ParentView? All scripts there works fine.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, i edited the question, please review

Comment: That's a weird error. Make sure you partial's html is well formed.

Comment: So your rendering of script is wrong - somewhere you output unexpected character... Looks like all information in the post is not needed - you only need one line where you output invalid JS.

Comment: @Jack,@AlexeiLevenkov, recently i upgraded from  jQuery 1.9 to 2.1.1. I'm using boostratp 2.3.2. there is maybe some incompatibility between them

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, forget the las error, i removed from th question, it was my fault trying everything i find to make this work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Partial View is loaded via ajax you need to initialize datepicker after the html is rendered on page so you need to put datepicker initialization script in success function callback:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (data, status) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $("#details").html(data);
                    $("#textBoxID").datepicker(); //  initialize datepicker for partial view element here

                })
```

For events you can write delegated events to make them work,choose the closest element of the partial view, i am using container of partial in which you are appending partial view html:

For click event:

```
$("#details").on("click","#someButtonId",function(){

// write event code here

})
```

For more detials of [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can see [**HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Ehsan, that worked!, This is a step forward, please what about the events, there is something else i have to do?

Comment: @Elio.Batista: anything and everything that needs to be initialized on something in the partial view (event handlers, etc.) must go in the call back. Otherwise, the actual elements you're trying to bind to don't exist yet.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, your comment complements this answer.

Comment: Events can be written in main view but you have to write delegated event

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, Can you edit your answer with a little sample of delegate events?

Comment: True, but you have to be careful with delegated events. They should be used sparingly and the element you bind to should be as close as possible in the DOM to the element generating the event: e.g., `#myModel` is good, `document` would be very bad.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, please look at this other question related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566414/jquery-events-stop-working-after-partial-view-post-in-asp-net-mvc4-part-ii/24569594#24569594

Answer (score 1):

If they are being loaded in by ajax you may need to give more context to your selectors.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myModal form', function () { ...
```

Comment: Your suggested sample is identical to OP version... not sure what exactly your suggestion is... Plus ID selector is already very specific since IDs are unique in valid HTML (and for invalid HTML one should not have any expectations for behavior of scripts/browser).

Comment: The selector `'#myModal form'` will not contain any `form` element inside `#myModal` that is added later.

Comment: +1. I see what you mean now... indeed your code makes sense, should not have read text you've added - sorry. (Clearly as "give more context" you mean "add filters for `on` call because form may be inserted later").

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no worries, you're just trying to help.

Comment: @Elio.Batista I'd try just having one of those partials loaded into the page normally with razor on page build and see if it works. If it does you'll have to see what's different about what you're loading in via ajax.

Comment: @Jack, i'm going to test and let you know

Comment: While this *may* work if set up properly, binding a delegate to something like `document` is going to severely degrade performance. Every single event anywhere on the page will will be run through the delegate check.