# jQuery events stop working after partial view post in asp.net mvc(4) Part II

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a View with the following layout 
[image]
The parent View is composed of several PartialViews. One of which is a list where each item has a corresponding Edit button which loads the item into another PartialView, but this is loaded via ajax into a modal bootstrap-dialog.

By hitting the Edit buttons partials view are loaded without problem in the modal dialog but after Submit a dialog the Edit buttons stop to fire the event and the modal does not get loaded anymore, i mean, the click handler for Edit button stops working.

I believe this is due to the fact that after posting the modal im ajax-reloading the List Partial View that contains Edit buttons and so i need to rebind the events. But by doing so  it would form a circular call beween the edit click event and modal form submit?

The scripts in the Parent View:

```
$(".btn.mylink").on("click", function () {            
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var url = "/SalidaDetalle/Edit/" + id;            
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $(".modal-body").html(data);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');

                $(".edit-detail").on('submit', function () {
                    $.post($(this).attr('action'),
                    $(this).serialize(), 
                    function (data, status) {                        
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        $("#details").html(data);

                    }).error(function (error, status, a, b) {
                        writeError('msgError', 'Error processing request. Please check errors and try again!');
                        $('.modal-body p.body').html(error.responseText);

                    });
                    return false;
                });

            });
        });
```

Note:
This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556680/using-jquery-with-partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc4)

Comment: it is a must for `$(".edit-detail")` to be put inside `$.get(url, function (data) {` ? I believe this cause some issue to your scripts

Comment: @Se0ng11, it is the way to wire the submit event for the modal form that is loaded with ajax.

Comment: after form submit list partial vew is refreshd via ajax?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, yes, so it's how I'm doing. Based in the comment of ChrisPratt  in your answer in the other question. Should i be using delegate events here?

Comment: @Elio.Batista you have to write delegated event in this scneario as element are created dynamically after DOM load

Comment: The quick fix could be adding script to partial view's '$(document).ready'. So it will get called everytime your partial view is refreshed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than bind the events to your buttons directly, anchor them to a containing block that doesn't get refreshed.  your events will continue to fire even if you have reloaded the inner content in that partial view.

```
$("#container").on("click",".btn.mylink", function (evt) {            
        var id = $(evt.currentTarget).data('id');
        var url = "/SalidaDetalle/Edit/" + id;            
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $(".modal-body").html(data);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    });

$("#container").on('submit',".edit-detail", function (evt) {
         $.post($(evt.currentTarget).attr('action'),
         $(evt.currentTarget).serialize(), 
         function (data, status) {                        
             $('#myModal').modal('hide');
               $("#details").html(data);

         }).error(function (error, status, a, b) {
              writeError('msgError', 'Error processing request. Please check errors and try again!');
            $('.modal-body p.body').html(error.responseText);

   });
   return false;
   });
```

You'll need to tweak the script and add the div with id container to your parent view, but you get the idea

Comment: Ok so, should I go with delegate event over binding event on ajax call? I read in other question that it is not recommended and that is why i do it like this.